# SQL make 2 different date types in one query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I made a query that has 3 tables: 1 with current year, last year and name of the country
[image]

As you can see the results of current year and last year are the same and that is the problem here. I want to use like. I want to make 1 query with one that has current year and one with last year.

I can use this for last year `YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

And from current year i can use this for example: `YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())`

My query:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT o.total_paid_tax_excl), 0)  AS CurrentYEAR,
    IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT o.total_paid_tax_excl), 0)  AS LastYEAR,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(l.name), 0) AS name
FROM
    expoled.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_address a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country_lang l ON c.id_country = l.id_country
WHERE
    l.id_lang = 7
        AND o.current_state IN (3 , 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121)
        AND l.name NOT IN ('Netherlands')
GROUP BY (l.name)
```

I can make seperate query but i want it in 1 query how can i archief this?
I did try Union but the results stayed the same.

I want to have it like this(this one does not work!! just for example[photoshop]
[image: ddd]

---

I think I need to change this part of the query

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl), 0)  AS CurrentYEAR,
    IFNULL(SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl), 0)  AS LastYEAR,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(l.name), 0) AS name
FROM
```

And add this to my query

For CurrentYEAR = `YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())`

For LastYEAR = `YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression (`if()` function or `case` statement) within the `sum()` aggregate function to add only those values that fit the criteria:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT if(YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),o.total_paid_tax_excl, 0)), 0)  AS CurrentYEAR,
    IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT if(YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1,o.total_paid_tax_excl, 0)), 0)  AS LastYEAR,
    IFNULL(l.name, '') AS name
FROM
    expoled.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_address a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country_lang l ON c.id_country = l.id_country
WHERE
    l.id_lang = 7
        AND o.current_state IN (3 , 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121)
        AND l.name NOT IN ('Netherlands')
GROUP BY IFNULL(l.name, '')
```

I also simplified the expression for the name field and made the `group by` clause consistent with it.

I did not change any other parts of the query, although I do not really agree with the `distinct` within the `sum()`, since you could have the same value paid as tax, but it is your data.

If your table has older data than the previous year's, then consider adding a where criteria to restrict the records for which the calculations are run.

Comment: Thanks mate, I also agree with the distinct part, will do something there later. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this (I added CASE for fields with SUM and a Where condition to extract only relevant years):

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(  CASE WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(o.date_date) =0 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl ELSE 0 END), 0)  AS CurrentYEAR,
    IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(o.date_date) =1 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl ELSE 0 END), 0)  AS LastYEAR,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(l.name), 0) AS name
FROM
    expoled.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_address a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_country_lang l ON c.id_country = l.id_country
WHERE
    l.id_lang = 7
        AND o.current_state IN (3 , 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121)
        AND l.name NOT IN ('Netherlands')
        AND YEAR(o.date_date) IN (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1)
GROUP BY (l.name)
```